# Avoid empty array elements in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to avoid empty array while filtering results while querying a collection in MongoDb

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5d429786bd7b5f4ae4a64790"),
    "extensions": {
      "outcome": "success",
      "docType": "ABC",
      "Roll No": "1"
    },
    "data": [
      {
        "Page1": [
          {
            "heading": "LIST",
            "content": [
              {
                "text": "<b>12345</b>"
              },

            ],

          }
        ],
        "highlights": [
          {
            "name": "ABCD",
            "text": "EFGH",

          }
        ],
        "marks": [
          {
            "revision": "revision 1",
            "Score": [
              {
                "maths": "100",
                "science": "40",
                "history": "90"
              },
              {
                "lab1": "25",
                "lab2": "25"
              }
            ],
            "Result": "Pass"
          },
          {
            "revision": "revision 1",
            "Score": [
              {
                "maths": "100",
                "science": "40"
              },
              {
                "lab1": "25",
                "lab2": "25"
              }
            ],
            "Result": "Pass"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am looking for results that has only "history" marks in the score array.

I tried the following query (in mongo 3.6.10) but it returns empty score array as well the array that has history as well

```
db.getCollection('student_scores').find({
  "data.marks.score.history": {
    $not: {
      $type: 10
    },
    $exists: true
  }
},
{
  "extensions.rollNo": 1,
  "data.marks.score.history": 1
})
```

Desired output is

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "rollNo": "1"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "marks": [
        {
          "Score": [
            {
              "history": "90"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Recommend you show a desired output doc from the query; the nuances of "only history marks in the score array" can change the nature of the query.  Also recommend providing 2 input docs, one that matches the desired output and one that does not.  And strip away `Page1`, `extensions`, etc.   These are not germane to the filter you seek and it makes it harder to "copy and test" the material.

Comment: I have corrected the josn. I am encountering nested array and my scenario involves not null to filter to fetch only history attribute

Comment: I think the data shape is still a little ... off.  I don't understand the design rationale of the `Score` array of objects.   You might simplify your design by having `Score` being a simple object, e.g. `Score: { "maths":100, "science":40, "lab1":25 }`  And also, those scores should numbers (ints) not strings...

Comment: Can you please check my answer? It ought to help with your requirement and simplify your result!

Answer (score 2):

I used something like the following;

```
db.getCollection('student_scores').aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.marks"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data.marks.Score"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "data.marks.Score.history": {
        $exists: true,
        $not: {
          $type: 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "extensions.Roll No": 1,
      "data.marks.Score.history": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$extensions.Roll No",
      history_grades: {
        $push: "$data.marks.Score.history"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

where I got the following result with your input (I think more readable than your expected output);

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "history_grades": [
      "90"
    ]
  }
]
```

where `_id` represents `"extensions.Roll No"` value for any given `data` set.

What do you think?

[check with a bigger input on mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZcaGcUUlVrl)

Comment: Not sure this tests for *only* history...?   Pretty sure this logic tests for at least one history, not only history.   But I am not 100% certain of the requirements from the OP.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti OP means for the final output when he says he wants ***only history***, for the output has two `Score` arrays, one with the expected `history` result and another empty object, and another with two empty objects. Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J0CriXH-gEI)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I still think the data design here with the `Score` array is a little off but here is solution that will ensure that a `Score` array contains **only** 1 entry and that entry is for a key of `history`.   We use dotpath array diving as a trick to get to the value of history.

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$data"}
,{$unwind: "$data.marks"}

,{$project: {
result: {$cond: [
    {$and: [ // if
        {$eq: [1, {$size: "$data.marks.Score"}]}, // Only 1 item...

        //  A little trick!  $data.marks.Score.history will resolve to an *array*
        //  of the values associated with each object in $data.marks.Score (the parent
        //  array) having a key of history. BUT: As it resolves, if there is no 
        // field for that key, nothing is added to resolution vector -- not even a null.
        //  This means the resolved array could
        //  be **shorter** than the input.  FOr example:
        //    > db.foo.insert({"x":[ {b:2}, {a:3,b:4}, {b:7}, {a:99} ]});
        //    WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
        //    > db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {z: "$x.b", n: {$size: "$x.b"}} } ]);
        //    { "z" : [ 2, 4, 7 ], "n" : 3 }
        //    > db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {z: "$x.a", n: {$size: "$x.a"}} } ]);
        //    { "z" : [ 3, 99 ], "n" : 2 }
        //
        //  You must be careful about this.
        //  But we also know this resolved vector is of size 1 (see above) so we can go ahead and grab
        //  the 0th item and that becomes our output. 
        //  Note that if we did not have the requirement of ONLY history, then we would not
        //  need the fancy $cond thing. 
        {$arrayElemAt: ["$data.marks.Score.history",0]} 
             ]},
    {$arrayElemAt: ["$data.marks.Score.history",0]},  // then (use value of history)
    null ] }   // else set null

,extensions: "$extensions"  // just carry over extensions
    }}

,{$match: {"result": {$ne: null} }} // only take good ones.
```